# Filter out FASTA files by specified sequence length in bash

Tags: awk, fasta

There's a FASTA file `assembly.fasta` containing contig names and corresponding sequences:

```
>contig_1
CCAATACGGGCGCGCAGGCTTTCTATCGCGCGGCCGGCTTCGTCGAGGACGGGCGGCGCA
AGGATTACTACCGCAGCGGC
>contig_2
ATATAAACCTTATTCATCGTTTTCAGCCTAATTTTCCATTTAACAGGGATGATTTTCGTC
AAAATGCTGAGGCTTTACCAAGATTTTCTACCTTGCACCTTCAGAAAAAAATCATGGCAT
TTATAGACGAAATTCTCGAGAAA
>contig_3
CGTGATCTCGCCATTCGTGCCG
```

I want to get only contigs longer than 30 letters and get a new FASTA file `assembly.filtered.fasta` containing only those long sequences with contig names, in this format:

```
>contig_1
CCAATACGGGCGCGCAGGCTTTCTATCGCGCGGCCGGCTTCGTCGAGGACGGGCGGCGCA
AGGATTACTACCGCAGCGGC
>contig_2
ATATAAACCTTATTCATCGTTTTCAGCCTAATTTTCCATTTAACAGGGATGATTTTCGTC
AAAATGCTGAGGCTTTACCAAGATTTTCTACCTTGCACCTTCAGAAAAAAATCATGGCAT
TTATAGACGAAATTCTCGAGAAA
```

Comment: Could you please do add more details how to achieve sample output in your question as its not clear(not my down-vote btw).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes, updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, tested and written with shown samples.

```
awk '
/^>/{
  if(sign_val && strLen>=30){
    print sign_val ORS line
  }
  strLen=line=""
  sign_val=$0
  next
}
{
  strLen+=length($0)
  line=(line?line ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(sign_val && strLen>=30){
    print sign_val ORS line
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
/^>/{                                ##Checking condition if line starts from > then do following.
  if(sign_val && strLen>=30){        ##Checking if sign_val is SET and steLen is SET then do following.
    print sign_val ORS line          ##Printing sign_val ORS and line here.
  }
  strLen=line=""                     ##Nullify variables steLen and line here.
  sign_val=$0                        ##Setting sign_val to current line here.
  next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  strLen+=length($0)                 ##Checking length of line and keep adding it here.
  line=(line?line ORS:"")$0          ##Creating line variable and keep appending it to it with new line.
}
END{                                 ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(sign_val && strLen>=30){        ##Checking if sign_val is SET and steLen is SET then do following.
    print sign_val ORS line          ##Printing sign_val ORS and line here.
  }
}
' Input_file                         ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I checked on my data and it works the way I expect it to be.

Answer (score 6):

Using `gnu-awk`, you may use this simpler version:

```
awk -v RS='>[^\n]+\n' 'length() >= 30 {printf "%s", prt $0} {prt = RT}' file
```

```
>contig_1
CCAATACGGGCGCGCAGGCTTTCTATCGCGCGGCCGGCTTCGTCGAGGACGGGCGGCGCA
AGGATTACTACCGCAGCGGC
>contig_2
ATATAAACCTTATTCATCGTTTTCAGCCTAATTTTCCATTTAACAGGGATGATTTTCGTC
AAAATGCTGAGGCTTTACCAAGATTTTCTACCTTGCACCTTCAGAAAAAAATCATGGCAT
TTATAGACGAAATTCTCGAGAAA
```

Comment: this solution outputs some contigs which are not present in outputs of two other solutions, though they are correct, dunno

Comment: this solution is somehow wrong because if I apply RavinderSingh13's solution on top of this, I still get some contigs filtered out

Comment: Not sure how it can be wrong, does this output not match with your expected output?

Comment: no, it doesn't. I applied 3 different solutions including this, 2 produce the same result and this one another. I'm not sure where it's wrong because the real data is too big to check errors manually

Comment: This is matching your provided output of your sample data. If you can provide me a longer sample then I can surely dig deeper.

Answer (score 3):

A very quick way to achieve what you are after is:

```
awk -v n=30 '/^>/{ if(l>n) print b; b=$0;l=0;next }
            {l+=length;b=b ORS $0}END{if(l>n) print b }' file
```

You might be also interested in [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk), it is an adapted version of awk which is tuned to process FASTA files

```
bioawk -c fastx -v '(length($seq)>30){print ">" $name ORS $seq}' file.fasta
```

---

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).

Comment: I would like to request to put comments if in case you have given down vote, else how could a person improve if someone not letting know the reason for downvote? Solution works well(for given example) and well explained then not sure what could be reason for silent down vote :(